# How to set SplashScreen in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, splash-screen

My App would load a splashScreen before launching the main window. How do you set the splashScreen running in Eclipse? There was a place to put the "splash:splashScreen.png" in NetBeans so that the App would start with the SplashScreen. Anything like that in Eclipse>

Comment: Have a look: [how to display splash screens](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Updating_Branding

Answer (score 3):

This link explains best how to add your splashscreen with netbeans -

http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial.

For Eclipse just add the -splash:path/to/image to VM arguments in the Debug/Run configurations panel.

Comment: Link is dead (2021)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the splash screen image has to be named splash.bmp as described here: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html. The splash screen is expected to be in the same plug-in as the product. If this is not true for you, you might want to make an explicit choice in the configuration.

Comment: That is for Eclipse RCP. What is the difference between RCP and normal Eclipse? Do I need to download something different?

Comment: Do you want to change the splash screen for the IDE?

Comment: RCP is the core of the Eclipse IDE and can be used to develop other plug-in based applications. If you just want to replace the splash screen of the Eclipse IDE you can search for splash.bmp and replace it with your own splash screen.

Comment: Now "the splash screen can display any gif, png, or jpeg image, with transparency, translucency, and animation." 

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the

> -splash:path/to/image

to VM arguments in the Debug/Run configurations under Arguments tab.

Answer (score 0):

Credits: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-change-eclipse-splash-welcome-screen-image

***Short version:*** replace `eclipse-jee-neon-R-win32\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3.v20170301-0400\splash.bmp` (your path will be very similar, navigate to it manually).

***Long version:***

> **1) Find “config.ini” file**
>
> Find the Eclipse configuration file “config.ini” in the following
>   location:
>
> `{eclipse.dir}\configuration\config.ini`
>
> **2) Find “osgi.splashPath”**
>
> Open the “config.ini” file, find the “osgi.splashPath” to find out where
>   Eclipse IDE's splash image is stored, e.g.:
>
> `osgi.splashPath=platform\:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform`
>
> The default splash image is stored in:
>
> `{eclipse.dir}/plugins/org.eclipse.platform folder`
>
> **3) Find the “splash.bmp” image**
>
> Find the “splash.bmp” image in the following location:
>
> `{eclipse.dir}/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.3.200.v200906111540/splash.bmp`
>
> (`3.3.200.v200906111540` is the Eclipse version in this case, it may be different than yours)
>
> **4) Replace it**
>
> Replace the default “splash.bmp” image with yours (you may want to keep a backup copy of the original).
>
> **5) Done**
>
> Restart your Eclipse IDE to see the result!

And now, for the real reason I wanted to post this answer: [image]