# How to add custom Splash Screen to Runnable Jar in Eclipes

Tags: eclipse, manifest, splash-screen, executable-jar

So I have a splash screen I want to add to a runnable jar file I create using Eclipse.

Right now the only way I can do this is by creating the Jar and Manually going into the jar file with WinRar and Editing the MANIFEST.MF files to point to the screen shot.

I was just wondering if there is an easier way to add the splash screen or give Eclipse a custom Manifest file to use on creating the Runnable Jar

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533403/how-to-set-splashscreen-in-eclipse) (direct link of the answer: [branding your application](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html)). You may find addtional information here: [How to create splash screens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `MANIFEST.MF` if you use General > Export as JAR

However, I myself do not know how to configure Eclipse such that it automatically adds it to the generated MANIFEST file.